# python minidom: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data' from url

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, minidom

I'm trying to parse a XML with Python using minidom. When I'm parsing a xml file from my filesystem I haven't any probnlem.

```
doc = minidom.parse("PATH HERE")
etiquetaDia = doc.getElementsByTagName("dia")
for dia in etiquetaDia:
    probPrecip = dia.getElementsByTagName("maxima")[0]      
    print(probPrecip.firstChild.data)
```

But when I try to parse a XML from a url with this code:

```
url = urllib2.urlopen('URL HERE') 
doc = minidom.parse(url)
etiquetaDia = doc.getElementsByTagName("dia")
for dia in etiquetaDia:
    probPrecip = dia.getElementsByTagName("maxima")[0]      
    print(probPrecip.firstChild.data)
```

I have an error message
[image]

Obviously it's the same XML in path and in url. Thanks

Comment: So what library are you using? When I do `pip search minidom` it gives `DOMWrap (0.1)`, `enhancedminidom (0.2)` and `gxml (0.5)`.

Comment: @Eddie it is in the python standard library I suppose: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html

Comment: @Luis Manrique Cool, could you post a sample XML file as well?

Comment: the library i'm using is from xml.dom import minidom
from urllib import request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the new urllib library instead like below.
It prints out Hello. Is that what you want?

```py
from xml.dom import minidom
from urllib import request

url = request.urlopen('http://localhost:8000/sample.xml')
doc = minidom.parse(url)
etiquetaDia = doc.getElementsByTagName("dia")
for dia in etiquetaDia:
    probPrecip = dia.getElementsByTagName("maxima")[0]
    print(probPrecip.firstChild.data)
```

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dia>
    <maxima>Hello</maxima>
</dia>
```

Comment: run `python3 -m http.server` to run a test HTTP server from the folder where your XML file is

Comment: I'm trying this option, but i have a new problem importing request. I'm working on it

Comment: `urllib` is a folder and `request` is a python file. Maybe you are missing something. When I try `import urllib` and `print(urllib.__path__)` I can see the urllib folder is in `/home/eddie/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/urllib`. Inside that folder I can see the file `request.py`. I would highly encourage you to use some sort of Python Virtual Environment if you haven't already.

Comment: finally it's run. Thank you for all!.

Answer (score 2):

The `urlopen` function returns an `HttpResponse` object. You must first call the `read()` method of this object to get the actual content of the response, and pass that to minidom

```
minidom.parse(url.read())
```

Comment: This read the xml file like a complete file without format. I can't use it